# Detecting 'transform: translate3d' support

Tags: html, css

Does anyone know how I would detect `transform: translate3d(x,y,z)` support is available?

My issue is that I want to use `translate3d` across browsers where it is supported because it tends to use hardware acceleration and hence smoother for animation, and then fall back to `translate` where its not.

Answer (score 44):

Check out [this solution](https://gist.github.com/3794226).

It is based on the fact that if a browser supports transforms, the value of

```
window.getComputedStyle(el).getPropertyValue('transform')
```

will be a string containing the transformation matrix, when a 3d transform is applied to the element `el`. Otherwise, it will be `undefined` or the string `'none'`, as in the case of Opera 12.02.

It works on all major browsers.

The code:

```
function has3d() {
    if (!window.getComputedStyle) {
        return false;
    }

    var el = document.createElement('p'), 
        has3d,
        transforms = {
            'webkitTransform':'-webkit-transform',
            'OTransform':'-o-transform',
            'msTransform':'-ms-transform',
            'MozTransform':'-moz-transform',
            'transform':'transform'
        };

    // Add it to the body to get the computed style.
    document.body.insertBefore(el, null);

    for (var t in transforms) {
        if (el.style[t] !== undefined) {
            el.style[t] = "translate3d(1px,1px,1px)";
            has3d = window.getComputedStyle(el).getPropertyValue(transforms[t]);
        }
    }

    document.body.removeChild(el);

    return (has3d !== undefined && has3d.length > 0 && has3d !== "none");
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in IE10 -- at least for me. I discovered after a bit of research that IE uses non-standard capitalization for the JS transform property. Thus, msTransform works for me, but MSTransform does not.

Comment: Yes I used this from a month ago and realized that IE10 didn't like it as 'Transform', as the first letter for style prefixes is a lower case (so it should be 'transform'). That makes me wonder if the OTransform should be oTransform instead.

Comment: @JonathanTonge No, in Opera it's `OTransform`.

Comment: I've noticed a problem. After adding this script the fonts in my site looks worst even after the `p` element has been removed from the DOM. What's wrong? Im testing it on Chrome. Looks exactly as when the element hasn't been removed: http://jsfiddle.net/69uer/

Comment: Although that example looks well after the element has been deleted. I don't know why I can not reproduce my problem on jsfiddle. Isn't there any way to make the text looks well even before the removal of the `p` element?

Comment: @Alvaro I don't see any problem on Chrome with the jsfiddle you posted. Can you please be more specific or post a web page where the problem happens?

Comment: @LorenzoPolidori sorry is not about your code, but about `translate3d`, which once used makes the text looks worse: http://jsfiddle.net/69uer/3/  vs http://jsfiddle.net/69uer/2/

Comment: @Alvaro still, I can't see any significant change in the text rendering on Chrome. There is a little difference on Safari, but very difficult to catch if you don't know about the change. `translate3d` is implemented by browsers using hardware acceleration provided by the platform and this may be configured differently by the different browsers.

Comment: @LorenzoPolidori maybe it is more noticeable with arial font and with no bold style. Here it is so noticiable: http://jsfiddle.net/69uer/7/ compare to this: http://jsfiddle.net/69uer/6/

Comment: @Alvaro for me it's still rendered the same, but we have different graphics hardware and that can make a huge difference in this case. Remember, with `translate3d` the result depends massively on the hardware acceleration capabilities of the machine where the browser runs.

Comment: @LorenzoPolidori ok, so it varies depending on the computer and browser implementation, which is kind of crazy :) Thanks though!

Comment: @envysea FF3.6? I'm not surprised, the current version is 25.0! what error? an exception? But, seriously, who's still using FF3.6? Anyway, if you still want to support it for some reason, you just need to identify which of the function calls throw an exception and surround them with a check like `if (!functionNotSupported) return false;`

Comment: Yup, that's what I did. Just sharing what I found out since some people (me) have no choice but to support these browsers.

Comment: Theoretically, if some weird browser does not support `getComputedStyle`, the function can throw an error. Fixed your answer.

Comment: Failing when adding an external script on the body: https://jsfiddle.net/c8ok9y1u/

Comment: You don't need to check for OTransform or msTransform for 3d transforms. First Opera version that supports them uses prefix -webkit-, IE 10 doesn't use prefix ms for transform property and IE9 doesn't support 3D at all. http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms3d

Comment: Should note that this will not work until document.body has been defined - so if it is running immediately in a script in `<head>`, it will throw an exception.

Answer (score 11):

The [original blog post announcing 3D transforms](http://www.webkit.org/blog/386/3d-transforms/) has an [image flip demo](http://www.webkit.org/blog-files/3d-transforms/image-flip.html), which does it with a media query, like this:

```
@media all and (-webkit-transform-3d) {
  /* Use the media query to determine if 3D transforms are supported */
  #flip-container {
    -webkit-perspective: 1000;
  }
  #flip-card {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s;
  }
  #flip-container:hover #flip-card {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  }
}
```

[This blog post](http://css-tricks.com/6731-css-media-queries/) has a good intro to media queries.  [This](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/mediaqueries) has some more details.

Comment: Clarifying, you could use the media query above to style an element only if transform3d is supported. For instance, apply a red color. Then you should use javascript to check if this element has the property applied or not. In our case, check if the color is black or red. If it's red, then 3d transform is supported.

Comment: This does not work on Chrome 38 on OS X. Is there a browser it DOES work on?

Answer (score 9):

You can try CCS3 [@supports](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-conditional/#at-supports):

```
@supports (transform: translate3d) {
  div {
    transform : translate3d(20px,0,0);
  }
}

@supports not (transform: translate3d) {
  div {
    transform: translate(20px,0);
  }
}
```

[Can I use @support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-featurequeries)

Comment: `@support` has a very bad... support at the moment. ios7 does not support it and only android 4.4 does: http://caniuse.com/css-featurequeries

Comment: Does `@support` have any javascript equivalent?

Comment: Seems like it should be `@supports (transform: translate3d(0,0,0,)) {` (or similar) instead? Need to give dummy args to `translate3d`.

Answer (score 4):

I'd suggest using [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/).

It does feature detection for a whole range of browser features, including 3D transforms. It also provides a method of specifying CSS rules for browsers which have various features or not, so it sounds like it will do exactly what you're looking for.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Sorry should have mentioned already tried that and it doesn't support the scenario above. Modernizr.csstransforms3d actually checks for support of `perspective` which is currently only available in Safari even though `-[browser-prefix]-transform: translate3d(x,y,z)` is available across chrome/ff.

Comment: @Jamie - ah well, so much for the obvious solution.  :-/ I wonder if the modernizr team are aware of this issue?

Comment: This isn't true – Modernizr detects 3d transforms fine for Chrome, and Fx doesn't support them. Have a look at http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/transforms/ in Firefox – the transforms don't work. If you visit http://www.modernizr.com/ in Chrome, you'll see it does detect 3d transforms fine in Chrome.

Comment: @Rich I'm afraid as stated Modernizr checks `perspective` to determine if 3d transforms are available. Perspective is unfortunately a completely different set of functionality. Here's the bit from the docs "For Modernizr, we test the browser's support for the perspective property.".

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't claiming that the perspective bit wasn't true, I was claiming that that check is fine, and doesn't give bad results. 3dtransforms are detected fine in Chrome, and Fx doesn't support them.

Comment: For anyone interested, the 3dtransforms detection function is here: https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/blob/master/modernizr.js#L606

Comment: Ah ok apologies. However we must be on different versions of chrome on mine it says its not supported :( ...even though it really is.

Comment: The only thing that it's heavy as hell.

Answer (score 4):

```
//The following is based on iScroll4's tests to determine if a browser supports CSS3 3D     transforms.
var has3d = function() {
    return ('WebKitCSSMatrix' in window && 'm11' in new WebKitCSSMatrix());
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This works if you need to test for 3d transforms support without using another library.

Comment: This works **only** on webkit browsers (e.g. Safari and Chrome). Firefox, which supports 3d transforms, returns *false* - actually the script stops its execution because the function `WebKitCSSMatrix` is not defined. Check this out for a cross-browser solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5661671/detecting-transform-translate3d-support/12621264#12621264

Answer (score 1):

Was tinkering around with a way to check for 3d support.. used this implementation from Jeffery Way in this [article](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-detect-css3-support-in-browsers-with-javascript--net-16444). Allows for less code and more use cases ;)

```
/**
* Test For CSS3 property support
* use 'perspective' to test for 3d support
*/
var supports = (function() {

    'use strict';

    var div = document.createElement('div'),
        vendors = 'Khtml ms O Moz Webkit'.split(' '),
        len = vendors.length;

    return function(prop) {

        if (prop in div.style) return true;

        prop = prop.replace(/^[a-z]/, function(val) {
            return val.toUpperCase();
        });

        while(len--) {
            if (vendors[len] + prop in div.style) {
                return true;
            } 
        }

        return false;
    };
})();

if(supports('perspective')) {
    // do 3d stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is adjusted for testing **3D transforms** support and other CSS3 features.

The plus of this code is that it detects the vendor prefix supported (if any). Call it:

```
testCSSSupport('transform')
```

Possible return values:

`false`,   when feature unsupported, or

```
{
    vendor: 'moz',
    cssStyle: '-moz-transform',
    jsStyle: 'MozTransform'
}
```

when feature supported

```
/**
 * Test for CSS3 feature support. Single-word properties only by now.
 * This function is not generic, but it works well for transition and transform at least
 */
testCSSSupport: function (feature, cssTestValue/* optional */) {
    var testDiv,
        featureCapital = feature.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + feature.substr(1),
        vendors = ['', 'webkit', 'moz', 'ms'],
        jsPrefixes = ['', 'Webkit', 'Moz', 'ms'],
        defaultTestValues = {
            transform: 'translateZ(0.5em) rotateY(10deg) scale(2)'
           // This will test for 3D transform support
           // Use translateX to test 2D transform
        },
        testFunctions = {
            transform: function (jsProperty, computed) {
                return computed[jsProperty].substr(0, 9) === 'matrix3d(';
            }
        };

    function isStyleSupported(feature, jsPrefixedProperty) {
        if (jsPrefixedProperty in testDiv.style) {
            var testVal = cssTestValue || defaultTestValues[feature],
                testFn = testFunctions[feature];
            if (!testVal) {
                return false;
            }

            //Assume browser without getComputedStyle is either IE8 or something even more poor
            if (!window.getComputedStyle) {
                return false;
            }

            testDiv.style[jsPrefixedProperty] = testVal;
            var computed = window.getComputedStyle(testDiv);

            if (testFn) {
                return testFn(jsPrefixedProperty, computed);
            }
            else {
                return computed[jsPrefixedProperty] === testVal;
            }
        }
    }

    //Create a div for tests and remove it afterwards
    if (!testDiv) {
        testDiv = document.createElement('div');
        document.body.appendChild(testDiv);
        setTimeout(function () {
            document.body.removeChild(testDiv);
            testDiv = null;
        }, 0);
    }

    var cssPrefixedProperty,
        jsPrefixedProperty;

    for (var i = 0; i < vendors.length; i++) {
        if (i === 0) {
            cssPrefixedProperty = feature;  //todo: this code now works for single-word features only!
            jsPrefixedProperty = feature;   //therefore box-sizing -> boxSizing won't work here
        }
        else {
            cssPrefixedProperty = '-' + vendors[i] + '-' + feature;
            jsPrefixedProperty = jsPrefixes[i] + featureCapital;
        }

        if (isStyleSupported(feature, jsPrefixedProperty)) {
            return {
                vendor: vendors[i],
                cssStyle: cssPrefixedProperty,
                jsStyle: jsPrefixedProperty
            };
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap uses following Code:

```
@media all and (transform-3d), (-webkit-transform-3d) {
    .carousel-inner > .carousel-item {
        transition: transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
        backface-visibility: hidden;
        perspective: 1000px;
    }
    .carousel-inner > .carousel-item.next,
    .carousel-inner > .carousel-item.active.right {
        left: 0;
        transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
    }
    .carousel-inner > .carousel-item.prev,
    .carousel-inner > .carousel-item.active.left {
        left: 0;
        transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    }
    .carousel-inner > .carousel-item.next.left,
    .carousel-inner > .carousel-item.prev.right,
    .carousel-inner > .carousel-item.active {
        left: 0;
        transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

tl:dr - Use user agent sniffing. Here is a script for detecting CSS 3D transform support across browsers: https://github.com/zamiang/detect-css3-3D-transform

I tried most of the methods in this post, among others like [Modernizer](http://modernizr.com) and [Meny](https://github.com/hakimel/meny)'s methods but could not support browsers like Firefox while maintaining a good experience for older browsers like Safari 4&5, iOS devices and Chrome on Retina MacBook pros (they all have their quirks).

CSS3 3D transforms involve interaction between the browser and the graphics card. The browser may be able to parse the 3D declarations but may not be able to properly instruct the graphics card in how to render your page. There are many possible outcomes ranging from the page rendering with lines across it (Safari 4) to the page rendering beautifully then crashing the browser seconds later (Safari on iOS4). Any ‘feature detection’ approach would unacceptably flag these as ‘supports CSS3 3D transforms’. This is one case where ‘feature detection’ fails and user agent sniffing (and lots of testing) wins hands down.

Most feature detection assumes a 'supports' or 'does not support' binary. This is not the case with CSS3 3D Transforms - there is a 'gradient of support'.

**CSS3 3D transform support can be separated into 4 levels:**

1. Reliably supports 3D transforms across most machines. For example: Safari 6
2. Can parse and apply 3D transform declarations but ignores the 3D parts. For example: Chrome on a Retina MacBook Pro.
3. Can parse and apply 3D transform declarations but renders in unacceptable ways. For example: Safari 4 and Safari 4/5 on Windows show lines across the page.
4. Cannot apply 3D transform declarations in any way. For example: IE or Firefox < v10

[This script](https://github.com/zamiang/detect-css3-3D-transform) will return `true` in scenario one and two but `false` for 3 and 4:

Note: new to participating in stackoverflow - please let me know if I should paste that code inline (it is a bit long)

Comment: Never encourage user agent sniffing.

Answer (score -2):

Using jQuery:

```
var cssTranslate3dSupported = false;
(function()
{
    var div = $('<div style="position:absolute;">Translate3d Test</div>');
    $('body').append(div);
    div.css(
    {
        'transform' : "translate3d(20px,0,0)",
        '-moz-transform' : "translate3d(20px,0,0)",
        '-webkit-transform' : "translate3d(20px,0,0)",
        '-o-transform' : "translate3d(20px,0,0)",
        '-ms-transform' : "translate3d(20px,0,0)"
    });
    cssTranslate3dSupported = (div.offset().left == 20);
    div.empty().remove();
})();
```

Comment: Good effort for making it cross browser, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score -6):

The author of [Hardware Accelerated Accordion](http://cubiq.org/dropbox/accordion/) checks like this:

```
var has3d = ('WebKitCSSMatrix' in window && 'm11' in new WebKitCSSMatrix())
```

Comment: Nice way to check for IE10. [/sarcasm]

Answer (score -7):

just simply use:

```
alert($.support.cssTransform3d);
```

this alerts true if supported and false if not

Comment: Are you sure about this? I don't see that one in [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.support/) and `$.support.cssTransform3d` is `undefined` in all the browsers I've checked.

Comment: This makes no sense, and obviously doesn't exist

Comment: Even if it exists, no one except jQuery should rely on it. See the documentation link @mu is too short posted - "Intended for jQuery's internal use".