# Detect / Condition to test if a browser supports css translate3d

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Detecting 'transform: translate3d' support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5661671/detecting-transform-translate3d-support)

Any way to Detect / Condition to test if a browser supports css translate3d:

```
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0px,0px,0px);
-moz-transform: translate3d(0px,0px,0px);
transform: translate3d(0px,0px,0px);
```

?