# Alternative of swapping out sticky nav bar for 60 FPS performance with scrollTop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, performance

I got a requirement that our sticky bar has to swap to be another bar if user scrolls down to a certain point. I have the working code but when I look at the performance it's quite slow. I use Chrome Dev Tool sometime it goes beyond 30 FPS which causes sluggishness on scrolling.

Here's the code I was wondering how do I code this and not use `scrollTop` to keep checking the position of the scroll bar for better performance?

I already use `debounce` to reduce the number of events being fired but still seeing some performance impact.

```
if ( this.dom.singleTitle.length ) { // this is to check if the element is present on the page
    this.dom.window.on('scroll', $.proxy( debounce( this.toggleNav, 50 ), this ) )
}



    toggleNav: function() {

        var screenTop = this.dom.document.scrollTop();
        if ( screenTop > this.dom.singleTitle.offset().top + 50 ) {
            if ( this.dom.mainNav.hasClass('expanded') ) {
                this.dom.mainNav.removeClass('expanded');
                this.dom.toggleTopbar.toggleClass('icon-menu icon-close');
                this.dom.body.removeClass('disable');
            }
            this.dom.headerShare.fadeIn(600);
        }
        else {
            this.dom.headerShare.fadeOut(600);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use CSS3 if possible and only jQuery as a fallback.
CSS3 animations are much more smooth. Instead of using `scrollTop` use the transformation `translate3d` and you'll notice the difference.

To see if css3 is supported or not, you could check [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5661671/detecting-transform-translate3d-support).

Also, try avoiding things such as `fadeIn` or `fadeOut` and the use of shadows or borders with radius.

Needles to say, images should be optimized in weight and size for a better performance when animating them.