# understanding complex media query that checks for css property support

Tags: html, css, media-queries

hey guys i came across the following media queries in bootstrap :

```
@media all and (transform-3d), (-webkit-transform-3d) {
  .carousel-inner > .item {
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: -o-transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
    transition: transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-perspective: 1000;
    perspective: 1000;
  }
```

and i was totally taken aback ! as i have no idea , what these media queries are doing ? no asking one of my seniour colleagues , i got the following asnwer :

> It is checking for css 3d transform support.

and the following link ::

[Link](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/tests/mediaqueries/animation.html) , now in the link , i see the following information ::

> Be very careful when using these. It’s only a matter of time before
>   we find a cheap device that doesn’t support, say, 3d-transitions but
>   pretends it does because the vendor forgot to turn off this media
>   query.

now , my question is what qxactly are these media queries and are they reliable ?

can somebody just tranlate this media query to how it would be read in plain english , my guess is it means the following ::

"the media query applies to all device widths and heights and orientations(@media all) , now check if this device browser supports tranform3d property or  -webkittransform3d" .

can somebody demistify this for me .

Comment: look this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/css_mediatypes.asp) up

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detecting 'transform: translate3d' support](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5661671/detecting-transform-translate3d-support)