# Check translate3d support not working when loading script in body

Tags: javascript, css, translate3d

This [proposed solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12621264/1081396) seems to work quite well in most scenarios but I noticed it fails to detect support for translate3d properties when a `<script>` tag is used within the `<body>`.

[Reproduction online](http://jsfiddle.net/c8ok9y1u/2/)

This is the function used to detect the 3d support:

```
function has3d() {
    if (!window.getComputedStyle) {
        return false;
    }

    var el = document.createElement('p'),
        has3d,
        transforms = {
            'webkitTransform':'-webkit-transform',
            'OTransform':'-o-transform',
            'msTransform':'-ms-transform',
            'MozTransform':'-moz-transform',
            'transform':'transform'
        };
    // Add it to the body to get the computed style.
    document.body.insertBefore(el, null);

    for (var t in transforms) {
        if (el.style[t] !== undefined) {
            el.style[t] = "translate3d(1px,1px,1px)";
            has3d = window.getComputedStyle(el).getPropertyValue(transforms[t]);
        }
    }

    document.body.removeChild(el);

    return (has3d !== undefined && has3d.length > 0 && has3d !== "none");
}
```

Comment: May I ask why this check ? translate3d is now supported in all browsers outside of Opera  and ie8 , The first link in your question was a stack that was aked 5 years ago . This may help http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms3d . So maybe detecting the browser instead of the support would make more sense seeing that the feature is widely supported.

Comment: There's still people out there still using IE 8 or Opera 12 :)