# Changing the flip side of an image or card using jQuery and CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

wasn't really sure how to best phrase the subject, so here's what I've got. I have two images set up as if they were opposite sides of a playing card. When you click on the front, the card spins and then lands on the back. When you click on the back, the card spins and lands on the front. While the card is spinning you can see both the back and front images. Works great!

I can't get it to work in jsfiddle, but here's the Codepen: https://codepen.io/dtarvin/pen/BRwEEW

Here's what's challenging me: I don't just want to play with two images here. I have thirteen images (Who, you may ask? You're right!) that I want to use. Image 1 will be face up when the page loads, and when you click on it, the image will spin, with image 2 and image 1 both showing during spin, then stopping with image 2 face up, like now. BUT when you click on image 2, the card spins and lands with a different image, image 3, face up. while the card is spinning you would see image 2 and 3 instead of image 1 and 2. Basically I want a new different image to pop up every time the current image is clicked, so that after 12 clicks you've seen all 13 images, with card spins for all of them.

The relevant code is as follows:

```js
$("#card").click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("flipped");
});
```

```css
#card.flipped {
  transform: /*translateY(100%) */
  rotateY(900deg);
}

.front {
  background-image: url("http://shillpages.com/dw/hartnw02.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
}

.back {
  background-image: url("https://s-media-cache-
 ak0.pinimg.com/originals/9b/ad/e9/9bade9c3c3daf12ea6feb9165e1ad214.jpg");
 background-size: cover;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="container">
  <div id="card">
    <div class="front">1</div>
    <div class="back">2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It seems that what's required is that the url be switched out of whatever side is not face up right before the card spins. I was thinking I would use an array to keep the url links. The trouble I'm having is figuring out how to do the switch. When I click on the image and .front is the class, how do I swap out the image on .back? I don't think a click event and (this) will work because the image I want to swap is not the one I'm clicking on. I don't want to have 13 different classes or id's, but I'm not sure how to set it up so that it will alternate switching the url on .front and .back. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: _"I don't think a click event and (this) will work because the image I want to swap is not the one I'm clicking on"_ - the elements you want to switch out the background images on have the class `front` and `back` respectively, so what else than those classes would you use the select them? This has little to do with where the click event happened, that is quite irrelevant. If you have trouble deciding which one of the two to manipulate alternately, a simple boolean flag helps.

Comment: So what you want to read, as an answer, is «use an image array and increment on click» ??

Comment: Okay, I modified my code. I put 3 images in an array (image 1 is set already, so those are images 2 through 4), set a boolean, set a for loop to loop through the array images, and set an if in that to apply to the .front or .back depending on whether the boolean is true or false. But now it's just going straight from image 1 to image 4.

Comment: Check my answer and my codepen... ;)

Answer (score 0):

**Use an image array and increment on click**.

By the way... I slowed your CSS animation just a bit... Was too fast!

```
transition: transform 7s;
```

So here is an example on how to use an array to change the images on click:
See it working in this [**Codepen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/BRmByZ?editors=1111).

```
var image_array = ["https://pbs.twimg.com/media/Br2wu9mIcAEgfTm.jpg:large",
                   "http://www.dyslexiaassociation.ca/gallery/famous/AlbertEinstein.jpg",
                   "http://images.collegexpress.com/cnc/insidecollege/list/list_760.jpg",
                   "http://cdn.lifedaily.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/mother.teresa.jpg",
                   "http://www.creativefan.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/25.jpg",
                   "http://www.awesomeinventions.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/last-bob.jpg"
                  ];
var img_count=0;
var side=true;

$("#card").click(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass("flipped");
  side=!side;
  console.log(side);

  if(side){
    $(".front").css("background-image", "url("+image_array[img_count]+")");
  }else{
    $(".back").css("background-image", "url("+image_array[img_count]+")");
  }

  // Increment counter
  img_count++;

  // If counter has reached the end of the image array, reset it.
  if(img_count==image_array.length){
    img_count=0;
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I actually wanted it to be fast, part of the effect.
There seems to be a weird flickering while it's spinning.  Any idea what's causing that?

Comment: I don't notice any flickering... It looks smooth on my side using Chrome 58. The CSS animation is driven by the browser... So it may depends on the browser you use or on you video card. In Firefox 53, it is a bit less smooth, but very correct. In Internet Exploder... Ha oups, sorry. In Internet Explorer 11, there is only one side, so the effect is completely failed. The CSS «preserve-3d» is not handled by IE.

Comment: A good thing you should do is to preload all your images in some hidden divs in the page. Just to have them loaded already when the animation needs it.

Comment: Well, you're right. It does work smoothly in Chrome. I have a Mac, so I was using Safari. I just compared, and it does appear to be a Safari problem. What do I do about that? I'm doing this for a website and want it to be compatible with all modern browsers.

Comment: Saddly... There is nothing to do about it. You'll have to perform a browser detection to serve some alternative content to the browsers which does not support «preserve-3d» correctly.

Comment: Look here about how to detect if the browser supports preserve-3d : http://stackoverflow.com/a/12621264/2159528